# advanced prolog tricks for 2019?

Tags: prolog

Recently I spend sometime with someone who'd been programming in Prolog, exclusively, for 2 decades. We spoke of new Prolog tricks that he used in 2019 that were not widely known in 2000. e.g. He's been working on grammar-based fuzzing for test generation... which sounds like a natural application for Prolog.

So I'm wondering what else is lighting-up Prolog? According,  I want to ask  three questions for experienced Prolog programmers:

Q1: What keeps them in that language?

Q2: Anyone got pointers to new generation Prolog applications?

Q3: Anyone got  some reference to new generation Prolog techniques? FYI:  I know most of  the Bratko/ Sterling/ O'Keith/ Clocksin&Mellish methods.

Comment: I would recommend asking this question on the [SWI-Prolog Discourse](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/) because as-stated, this is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: (Somehow I missed this question - too late): Q0 (new tricks): 1mo, call/N - while invented in the 1980s, it took a while to get accepted. And even now its consequences have not been appreciated in full. This permits well  typed higher-order programming. 2do, mature CLP(FD/Z) implementations conforming to ISO. 3tio, dif/2 to the masses qua [if_/3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/772868).

Comment: Q3: [tag:failure-slice], [if_/3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01590)

Answer (score 3):

I can refer you to Logtalk language.
it augments Prolog with objects.

https://logtalk.org/